# Sequelize create through association

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I'm working on a create method for an association between two classes.  The sequelize documentation indicates that this can be done in one step using includes

```
IntramuralAthlete.create(intramuralAthlete,{
         include: [Person]
    }).then((data,err)=>{
         if(data)res.json(data);
         else res.status(422).json(err);
    }).catch(function(error) {
         res.status(422).json({message: "failed to create athlete", error: error.message});
});
```

My model association looks like this

```
var Person = require('../models').person;
var IntramuralAthlete = require('../models').intramuralAthlete;

IntramuralAthlete.belongsTo(Person);
```

And the value of intramural athlete when I log it is

```
{ 
   person: 
   { firstName: 'Test',
     lastName: 'User',
     email: 'test@user.com'
  },
  grade: '12th',
  organizationId: 1 
}
```

But I get the error `notNull Violation: personId cannot be null`.   This error makes it sound like something is wrong with the way I'm indicating to Sequelize that I'm intending to create the personId in that same call.

Is there something wrong in the way I indicate to the `create` statement what associated tables to create with the IntramuralAthlete?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have also tried with the following structure with the same result

```
{ 
  Person: { 
    firstName: 'Test',
    lastName: 'User',
    email: 'test@user.com'
 },
 grade: '12th',
 organizationId: 1 
}
```

My model is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('intramuralAthlete', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
    },
    grade: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    age: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },
    school: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    notes: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    guardianId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'contact',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    personId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'person',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    mobileAthleteId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'mobileAthlete',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    organizationId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'organization',
        key: 'id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'intramuralAthlete'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose that your models are named `Person` and `IntramuralAthlete` (first arguments of `sequelize.define` method). In this case, when you create an association like yours, and do not define the `as` attribute, your `create` data object should look as follows

```
{
    Person: {
        firstName: 'Test',
        lastName: 'User',
        email: 'test@user.com'
    },
    grade: '12th',
    organizationId: 1 
}
```

If you want to use `person` instead (just as in your code), you should define the association a little bit differently

```
IntramuralAthlete.belongsTo(Person, { as: 'person' });
```

Then, you would have to perform some changes in the `create` query in the `include` attribute of the `options` like this

```
IntramuralAthlete.create(data, {
    include: [
        { model: Person, as: 'person' }
    ]
}).then((result) => {
    // both instances should be created now
});
```

**EDIT**: Trick the `save()` method with empty value of `personId`

You can maintain the `allowNull: false` if you do something like that

```js
{
    person: {
        // person data
    },
    personId: '', // whatever value - empty string, empty object etc.
    grade: '12th',
    organizationId: 1
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Disable validation when creating.

This case assumes that the validation is turned off. It seems like a bad idea to omit model validation, however there still maintains the database table level validation - defined in migrations, where it can still check if `personId` value was set

```js
IntramuralAthlete.create(data, {
    include: [
        { model: Person, as: 'person' }
    ],
    validate: false
}).then((result) => {
    // both instances should be created now
});
```

In this case the `data` object can be as in your example - without the `personId` attribute. We omit the model level validation which allows to pass `null` value, however if during the `save()` method it would still be `null` value - database level validation would throw an error.

Comment: What you have said makes sense, but I tried the suggested change to the object structure (included as an edit in my question), and it fails with the same error.

Comment: Yup, that might also happen. Could you also add the `IntramuralAthlete` model definition code?

Comment: Added model as requested

Comment: I didn't take it into consideration at first - my answer would work if the `personId` would not have the `allowNull: false` attribute. In such a case I need to rethink it. Will let you know if got something useful :)

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Not super pleased that in order to do a one call create, you have to remove contraints on the foreign key, but it's better than giant nested chains of promises in our situation.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I edited the answer with some workaround for the problem, maybe it will satisfy you.

Comment: I like this much better.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you associatea a model with **belongsTo**, sequelize will add automatically the target model primary key as a foreign key in the source model. in most of cases you don't need to define it by yourself, so in your case when you define `IntramuralAthlete.belongsTo(Person)` sequelize adds `PersonId` as a foreign key in `IntramuralAthlete`. your `IntramuralAthlete` model should looks like:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('intramuralAthlete', {
    grade: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    age: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: true
    },
    school: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    notes: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
 });
};
```

now you can create an `intramuralAthlete` like your code above. for example:

```
 let data = {
   Person: {
     firstName: 'Test',
     lastName: 'User',
     email: 'test@user.com'
   },
   grade: '12th',
   notes: 'test notes'
 }
IntramuralAthlete.create(data, {include: [Person]}).then((result) => {
// both instances should be created now
});
```

be carefull with the model name. 
second I suppose that your `IntramuralAthlete` model has more than one `belongsTo` association. just you need to define them as the previous one association and sequelize will add their primary keys as foreign keys in the `IntramuralAthlete` model.

third, when you define a model, sequelize adds automatically an `id` datafield as a primary key and autoincrement and also adds `createdAt` and `updatedAt` datafields with a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` value, so you don't need to define them in your model